# WPForm not sending data to Mailchimp list. How to Fix it?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, wpforms

I created a contact form using WPForm. My goal is for the data to seamlessly land in the Mailchimp list whenever someone fills out the form. I've connected Mailchimp with WpForm through the Advanced Form Integration plugin. Yet, WpForm isn't shooting its data over to the Mailchimp list. Any ideas on fixing this glitch? Thanks!

I experimented with the GPL version of WpForm along with its original Mailchimp connector Addon, but it didn't work.
Next, I attempted to use the Tablesome plugin to integrate WpForm with Mailchimp, but alas, no success.